# How to bring instance of codeigniter 4 in to my upper directory without affecting its content

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

If my **Codeigniter 4** files are in

```
www.website/projects/my_cifiles
```

and my Codeigniter `index.php` files is located in

```
www.website/projects/my_cifiles/public
```

How can I copy an instance of Codeigniter into

```
www.website/
```

without Codeigniter affecting the index file in `www.website/` ?

Will `get_instance()` bring the codeigniter class into www.website/ directory?

Answer (score 1):

If you place a file called 'index.php' into www.website/ and in that file you include the following line:

```
require_once('/projects/my_cifiles/public/index.php');
```

It will point your browser to the public folder and continue from there.